# android:ellipsize does not not work as I expected

Tags: android

I want to show a text in a single line. If the string it too long, I hope to show **...** at the end of the line, ex. "Hello World!!!!...". Below is my code.

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:text="Hello World!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!" />
```

because `android:singleLine` is deprecated, I tried to use `android:lines="1"` or `android:maxLines="1"` instead of `android:singleLine=true`. But it shows

> Hello ...

not

> Hello World!!!...

Please guide.

Comment: your code is fine..its working i checked

Comment: your code is fine, just put long string to checck..

Comment: hey guys, do you run this code in the real devices?? because it's fine in Preview of Android Studio, fails in the real devices

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the `width` property of `TextView`. It should be `wrap_content` or must have large value then `100dp` to show long text.

```
<TextView
android:layout_width="100dp" /*This should be wrap or greater than 100dp*/
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:ellipsize="end"
android:singleLine="true"
android:text="Hello World!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!" />
```

Comment: in my app, i need to support this feature in a fixed size textview. and why android:singleLine="true" is workable

Comment: If you need to fix width then it must cause issue on different screen sizes because dpi is different for different screen resolutions and sizes and what dou mean by- android:singleLine="true" is workable

Comment: I have updated my question, and explain what "android:singleLine is workable" means .

Comment: Increase width of your TextView to 180dp or decrease text size to see the difference.

Answer (score 0):

use `android:ellipsize="end"` and `android:maxLines="1"

Comment: not working. it shows "Hello...", but i want is "Hello World!!..."

Comment: increase the width of your textview to check.. change it to may be 150dp and check if its working

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem is *layout_width*.
Yo can try to limit characters number and set width to *wrap_content*
So, use `android:maxLength="maxNumber"`

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:maxLength="10"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:maxLines="1"
    <!-- deprecated android:singleLine="true" -->
    android:text="Hello World!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!" />
```

Comment: still not working. it shows "Hello Worl", but i want "Hello Worl..."